# How to add Flutter MethodChannel to Android Application.class?

Tags: android, flutter

How to add Flutter MethodChannel to Android Application.class without creating a flutter plugin?
I can do it in Activity, but somehow I cannot access MethodChannels if I add them in Application.class.

Android:

Logs: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getPreferences on channel ...)

```
class App : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    setPreferencesChannel()
}

override fun registerWith(reg: PluginRegistry?) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(reg)
}

private fun setPreferencesChannel() {
    val channel = MethodChannel(FlutterEngine(this).dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, applicationContext.packageName + "/preferences")
    channel.setMethodCallHandler { call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result ->
        when (call.method) {
            "getPreferences" -> {
                val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                val map = HashMap<String, Any?>()
                map["font_size"] = prefs.getInt("font_size_main", 0)
                result.success(map)
            }
            else -> result.notImplemented()
        }
    }
}}
```

Flutter:

```
    class PreferencesChannel {
  static final _channel =
      MethodChannel(BuildConfig.packageName + '/preferences');

  PreferencesChannel._();

  static Future<dynamic> getPreferences() async {
    try {
      return _channel.invokeMethod('getPreferences');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      Logger.logError(e.message, 'PreferencesChannel: getPreferences');
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```